# AngularJS - ui-routing with ng-click not working properly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click, ng-view

I'm using ui-router for creating some routes and I'm getting this very weird thing happening.

I have this route config

```
    .state('chapter_route', {
    url: '/book/:chap',
    templateUrl: "views/chapter.html",
    params: { chap: null}
})
```

So when I clink on:

```
<a ui-sref="chapter_route({ chap: getChapter.title})">CHAPTER:</a>
```

It redirects me, as I wanted, to this following ui-view:

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>{{getChapter.title}}</p>
                            {{getChapter.content}}
                        </div>
    </div>
......
......
        <div class="panel panel-default" data-ng-repeat="cha in allChapters">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <a ui-sref="chapter_route({ chap: cha.title})" ng-click="changeChapter(chap)">{{cha.title}}</a> {{cha.content | limitTo: 100}}.
                <button ng-click="changeChapter(article)">PRESS ME </button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

As you can see I have another `<a>` tag here that is supposed to send me to a different chapter and also changes the value of chapter

getChapter looks something like:

```
$scope.allChapters = [
    {
        title: "title 1",
        chapter: "the whole chapter goes here"
    },
    {
        title: "title 2",
        chapter: "the whole chapter 2 goes here"
    },
    {
        title: "title 3",
        chapter: "the whole chapter 3 goes here"
    }
    ];

$scope.getChapter = $scope.allChapters[0];
```

and changeChapter looks like this:

```
$scope.changeChapter = function(chap){
    $scope.getChapter = chap;
    console.log($scope.getChapter);
};
```

So here's what's really happening:
I start by showing the first chapter and create links for all the next chapters. If I click on the `<a>` tag it changes the value of getChapter using ng-click and prints it on the console perfectly fine but it doesn't change the ui-view for this chapter unless I click it again. I can see the ui-view change for a fraction of a second but it doesn't stay, it quickly loads the ui-view for the first chapter. But if I click again, it shows the chapter I'm clicking on. So, I need to click twice for it to change which is very weird.

However if I decide to click on the button "PRESS ME" it changes directly into the next chapter in the ui-view.
I want to be able to click on the `<a>` tag and change to a different ui-view and at the same time having a different url, according to the chapter title.

Any ideas of what might be causing this weird error?

Thank you :)

EDIT:

https://plnkr.co/edit/D6f9Q3fhL294DukEZFOz?p=preview

I added a simple plunker with the issue we're discussing so you can have a better view of what I'm talking about.

Comment: can you make http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/D6f9Q3fhL294DukEZFOz?p=preview
I created a plunker. 
When you click on "title 2" or "title 3" it should not only change the url and value of getChapter, but also change the   '<div class="container" ui-view></div>'

Comment: check this plunker link : https://plnkr.co/edit/Ir1shTsbQ8eNQah4P3YR?p=preview

Comment: I see! The problem is the url is not changing accordingly with the chapter's title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your controller code `$scope.getChapter = $scope.allChapters[0];` here for all case you are hard coding current chapter with first chapter, so in all case it will render the same only.
Replace it with `if (!$stateParams.chap) {
      $scope.selectedChapter = $scope.allChapters[0];
    }`. It will solve your issue. [Updated Plunker with Fix](https://plnkr.co/edit/i24mqihEMtiJzKIEewMp?p=preview)

Comment: I was just trying to use this with my code but I get something that got me thinking. When you click on the chapters on the right side, the controller will run again and this state $stateParams will be defined and therefore it will not know the variable $scope.selectedChapter. I did a console.log($scope.selectedChapter) in my code after clicking in a different chapter and it says undefined

Comment: Check this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/D6f9Q3fhL294DukEZFOz?p=preview
Because before I used different controllers, and not always the same controller as in the previous simple example, it totally changes

Comment: I got! I used your if statement and then decided to run a loop and find the chapter in that was coming through $stateParams.chap
Thank you :)

Comment: The best way to do is to move your all chapters in a service and get the selected chapter based on stateParams

Answer (score 1):

[Check this plunker for your working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ir1shTsbQ8eNQah4P3YR?p=preview)

you have to use `$state.go` for this.

```
$scope.changeChapter = function(chap){
    $scope.getChapter = chap;
    $state.go('chapter_route', {chap: chap});
    console.log($scope.getChapter);
};
```

NOTE: don't forgot to add `$state` in controller.

Comment: $stage or $state?

Comment: `$state` , i am using this for move to other page.

Comment: I just added $state but nothing happens now. It changes the url, it changes the object value on click but it does not display it. The display in ui-view keeps the same of index 0.

Comment: @N.Car, check this link: http://www.codelord.net/2015/06/20/simple-pagination-and-url-params-with-ui-router/

Comment: @chiragsatapara I tried changing the $state.go but the weird displaying still happens. It does not change the view even though the object and url are different

Comment: @N.Car , is this answer helpful to you?

Comment: It works with the views, but the URL isn't correct. It should be the title and not an index. But thank you for the help :)